# How to control instantiation of View and ViewModel in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

My silverlight application has 2 pages, PageA and PageB. Each page is binding to it corresponding ViewModel, PageAViewModel and PageBViewModel. (I set ViewModel to View's DataContext inside xaml.)

User can switch back and forth between these pages, when user switch between these pages they create new instance of PageA and PageB which also create new object of its ViewModel which I don't want. I try to set [NavigationCacheMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.navigationcachemode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to [Enable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcachemode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), now all Views create instance only first time user navigate to that page this also mean ViewModel has only one instance.

I want to know how to control UI to create only one instance of View and control when to create new instance of its ViewModel?

Comment: Check out Caliburn Micro.  It offers a nice way to do ViewModel first or View first presentation.

Comment: I'm slightly puzzled by your question... do you want to know how to do this in general, or what you should do for your particular app? I ask because it seems you have already achieved what you ask for.

Comment: @slugster: I want to know how to control number of instance (of View and ViewModel) to create. Now it create new instance every time I navigated to that page and it call to server which is not good (open page A, it create new instance and call server for 2 times.

Comment: But you said: *now all Views create instance only first time user navigate to that page this also mean ViewModel has only one instance.* Hasn't this achieved what you wanted?

Comment: @slugster: I want to create instance of View only once but I want to control how to create instance of ViewModel, for example, PageAViewModel create instance every time in navigated to but PageBViewModel create instance only once. (I'm not good in English, sorry for confused you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where IOC (Inversion Of Control), like Unity, comes in handy.

You would simply register the ViewModel as a singleton (*one only, ever*) with Unity.

Rather than embed a ViewModel in the View (really bad practice to hardwire them like that ), you specify what *type of ViewModel* the View wants when it is created and the matching ViewModel would be "injected" into the view.

Basic MVVM, without some other injection framework, does not give you much out of the box (aside from a separation from the view).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using MVVM light framework for your application. It supports a view model locator concept which avoids recreating the instance of your VM each time a user clicks on a page. Take a look at a presentation by  Laurent Bugnion [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX10/EX14).